# Kafka Connect. OffsetStorageReader throws exception, only at the first poll(). On the next poll() gets sourceOffset without exception

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Line

> context.offsetStorageReader().offset(sourcePartition());

produces exception at the first poll.
On the next polling, there is no exception. Is it possible to fix it without wrapping extra checking around **getLatestSourceOffset()** like adding field to determine if it's the first poll? Or there is no way to avoid it and we should add checking?

**kafka-connect-api version: 0.10.2.0-cp1**

```
2022-06-19 05:52:34,538 ERROR [pool-1-thread-1] (OffsetStorageReaderImpl.java:102) - CRITICAL: Failed to deserialize offset data when getting offsets for task with namespace CryptoPanicSourceConnector. No value for this data will be returned, which may break the task or cause it to skip some data. This could either be due to an error in the connector implementation or incompatible schema.
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: JsonConverter with schemas.enable requires "schema" and "payload" fields and may not contain additional fields. If you are trying to deserialize plain JSON data, set schemas.enable=false in your converter configuration.
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.toConnectData(JsonConverter.java:309)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.OffsetStorageReaderImpl.offsets(OffsetStorageReaderImpl.java:96)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.OffsetStorageReaderImpl.offset(OffsetStorageReaderImpl.java:54)
        at com.delphian.bush.CryptoPanicSourceTask.getLatestSourceOffset(CryptoPanicSourceTask.java:97)
        at com.delphian.bush.CryptoPanicSourceTask.poll(CryptoPanicSourceTask.java:61)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:162)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:139)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:182)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**worker.properties**

```
bootstrap.servers=localhost:29092
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter.schemas.enable=true

internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=true
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=true

rest.port=8086
rest.host.name=127.0.0.1
offset.storage.file.filename=offsets/standalone.offsets
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000
```

**SourceTask**

```
    public List<SourceRecord> poll() throws InterruptedException {
        List<SourceRecord> records = new ArrayList<>();
        Optional<Long> sourceOffset = getLatestSourceOffset();
        CryptoNewsResponse newsResponse = // getNewsFromApi

        // Filter which news add to records based on sourceOffset. Shortened for brevity 
        for (CryptoNews news : filteredNews) {
            records.add(generateRecordFromNews(news));
        }

        return records;
    }
    
    
   private Optional<Long> getLatestSourceOffset() {
        Map<String, Object> offset = context.offsetStorageReader().offset(sourcePartition());
        if (offset != null) {
            Object id = offset.get("id");
            if (id != null) {
                Long latestOffset = Long.valueOf((String) id);
                return Optional.of(latestOffset);
            }
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }
    
    private SourceRecord generateRecordFromNews(CryptoNews cryptoNews) {
        return new SourceRecord(
                sourcePartition(),
                sourceOffset(cryptoNews),
                config.getString(TOPIC_CONFIG),
                null,
                CryptoNewsSchema.NEWS_KEY_SCHEMA,
                buildRecordKey(cryptoNews),
                CryptoNewsSchema.NEWS_SCHEMA,
                buildRecordValue(cryptoNews),
                Instant.now().toEpochMilli()
        );
    }
    
    

    private Map<String, String> sourceOffset(CryptoNews cryptoNews) {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(CryptoNewsSchema.ID_FIELD, cryptoNews.getId());
        return map;
    }
```

**UPDATE**

I don't use *Avro* and *Protobuf*.
My news schema:

```
public static final Schema NEWS_SCHEMA = SchemaBuilder.struct()
            .name(SCHEMA_NAME)
            .version(FIRST_VERSION)
            .field(NewsSourceSchema.SCHEMA_NAME,  SOURCE_SCHEMA)
            .field(CurrencySchema.SCHEMA_NAME, SchemaBuilder.array(CURRENCY_SCHEMA).optional())
            .field(KIND_FIELD, Schema.OPTIONAL_STRING_SCHEMA)
            .field(DOMAIN_FIELD, Schema.OPTIONAL_STRING_SCHEMA)
            .field(TITLE_FIELD, Schema.OPTIONAL_STRING_SCHEMA)
            .field(PUBLISHED_AT_FIELD, Schema.OPTIONAL_STRING_SCHEMA)
            .field(SLUG_FIELD, Schema.OPTIONAL_STRING_SCHEMA)
            .field(ID_FIELD, Schema.OPTIONAL_STRING_SCHEMA)
            .field(URL_FIELD, Schema.OPTIONAL_STRING_SCHEMA)
            .field(CREATED_AT_FIELD, Schema.OPTIONAL_STRING_SCHEMA)
            .build();
            
     public Struct toConnectData(CryptoNews cryptoNews) {
        Struct struct = new Struct(CryptoNewsSchema.NEWS_SCHEMA)
                .put(NewsSourceSchema.SCHEMA_NAME, NewsSourceConverter.INSTANCE.toConnectData(cryptoNews.getSource()))
                .put(CryptoNewsSchema.KIND_FIELD, cryptoNews.getKind())
                .put(CryptoNewsSchema.DOMAIN_FIELD, cryptoNews.getDomain())
                .put(CryptoNewsSchema.TITLE_FIELD, cryptoNews.getTitle())
                .put(CryptoNewsSchema.PUBLISHED_AT_FIELD, cryptoNews.getPublishedAt())
                .put(CryptoNewsSchema.SLUG_FIELD, cryptoNews.getSlug())
                .put(CryptoNewsSchema.ID_FIELD, cryptoNews.getId())
                .put(CryptoNewsSchema.URL_FIELD, cryptoNews.getUrl())
                .put(CryptoNewsSchema.CREATED_AT_FIELD, cryptoNews.getCreatedAt());

        List<Currency> currencies = Optional.ofNullable(cryptoNews.getCurrencies()).orElse(new ArrayList<>());
        final List<Struct> items = currencies.stream()
                .map(CONVERTER::toConnectData)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        struct.put(CurrencySchema.SCHEMA_NAME, items);
        return struct;
    }
```

**UPDATE 2**

connector.properties

```
name=CryptoPanicSourceConnector
tasks.max=1
connector.class=com.delphian.bush.CryptoPanicSourceConnector
topic=crypto-news
```

Startup command:

```
connect-standalone config/worker.properties config/custom-connector.properties
```

Answer (score 1):

When using plain JSON data with Connect, you may see this error message: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: JsonDeserializer with schemas.enable requires "schema" and "payload" fields and may not contain additional fields.

You will need to set the schemas.enable parameters for the converter to false for plain text with no schema.

```
bootstrap.servers=localhost:29092

key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=false

value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter.schemas.enable=false
```

Comment: @ChrisDist the exception still happens. I use schemas, probably it's because of them. Also added this information to question. (OffsetStorageReaderImpl.java:102) - CRITICAL: Failed to deserialize offset data when getting offsets for task with namespace CryptoPanicSourceConnector. No value for this data will be returned, which may break the task or cause it to skip some data. This could either be due to an error in the connector implementation or incompatible schema.
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: JsonConverter with schemas.enable requires "schema" and "payload"

Comment: Okay. Then I believe, you should have the data_converter_class or connector.class properties should be added in the workers properties, which points to your Schema implementation class that implements that extends DataConverter. For example public class SourceConnectorDataConverterImpl extends DataConverter. And in the workers properties data_converter_class: SourceConnectorDataConverterImpl

Comment: @ChrisDist, added connector.properties and startup command to question. Can't find the reference to data_converter_class in Kafka documentation with example. It would replace the way how kafka tries to deserialize offset  at context.offsetStorageReader().offset(sourcePartition())? Or it would affect sending records mechanism? The problem happens only with this line. Sending CryptoNews with custom schema as SourceRecord works fine and I can deserialize the response at consumer